# How to order by group "row_number" in ElasticSearch

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, grouping, elasticsearch-aggregation

I have a database with Products and each product has an Id, Name, ManufacturerId, CategoryId and UserScore.

I want to retrieve all Products by a given Category sorted by UserScore, but avoiding many products of same Manufacturer listed together.

With the following query they all stuck together:

```
SELECT
P.ProductId, P.Name, P.ManufacturerId, P.UserScore
FROM Products P
WHERE P.CategoryId = 1
ORDER BY P.UserScore
```

This is the result in T-SQL

[image: This is the result ordered by UserScore but in yellow are different products same manufacturer]

In T-SQL I came up with a solution like the following, where Products are grouped in no more than 2 elements by Manufacturer, and it suits perfectly my needs:

```
SELECT T.*
FROM (
       SELECT
             P.ProductId, P.Name, P.ManufacturerId, P.UserScore,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY P.ManufacturerId ORDER BY P.UserScore DESC) RN
       FROM Products P
       WHERE P.CategoryId = 1
) T
ORDER BY T.UserScore / CEILING(RN/2.0) DESC
```

[image: This is the result expected in T-SQL]

How could I implement a ElasticSearch Query to mimic this behaviour?

Any ideas?

The index in elasticsearch would be like this, this is just an abstract example:

```
{"ProductId": "157072", "Name": "Product 157072", "ManufacturerId": "7790", "UserScore": "100000", "CategoryId": "1"},
{"ProductId": "296881", "Name": "Product 296881", "ManufacturerId": "6921", "UserScore": "35400", "CategoryId": "1"},
{"ProductId": "353924", "Name": "Product 353924", "ManufacturerId": "54616", "UserScore": "25000", "CategoryId": "1"},
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the collapse search function to group all the manufacturers:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/collapse-search-results.html

Visit "inner_hits" to control the collapsed results behavior.

```json
# Indexing Documents
POST test_so/_bulk
{ "index" : {} }
{"ProductId": "157072", "Name": "Product 157072", "ManufacturerId": "7790", "UserScore": 100000, "CategoryId": "1"}
{ "index" : {} }
{"ProductId": "296881", "Name": "Product 296881", "ManufacturerId": "6921", "UserScore": 35400, "CategoryId": "1"}
{ "index" : {} }
{"ProductId": "353924", "Name": "Product 353924", "ManufacturerId": "54616", "UserScore": 25000, "CategoryId": "1"}

# Filtering by Category: 1, collapsing by Manufacturer and sorting by UserScore
POST test_so/_search
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "CategoryId.keyword": {
        "value": "1"
      }
    }
  },
  "collapse": {
    "field": "ManufacturerId.keyword"
  }, 
  "sort": [
    {
      "UserScore": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Results

```json
{
  "took": 22,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 1,
    "successful": 1,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": {
      "value": 3,
      "relation": "eq"
    },
    "max_score": null,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "test_so",
        "_id": "0amBPYQBJRm5qR4vd6NE",
        "_score": null,
        "_source": {
          "ProductId": "157072",
          "Name": "Product 157072",
          "ManufacturerId": "7790",
          "UserScore": 100000,
          "CategoryId": "1"
        },
        "fields": {
          "ManufacturerId.keyword": [
            "7790"
          ]
        },
        "sort": [
          100000
        ]
      },
      {
        "_index": "test_so",
        "_id": "0qmBPYQBJRm5qR4vd6NE",
        "_score": null,
        "_source": {
          "ProductId": "296881",
          "Name": "Product 296881",
          "ManufacturerId": "6921",
          "UserScore": 35400,
          "CategoryId": "1"
        },
        "fields": {
          "ManufacturerId.keyword": [
            "6921"
          ]
        },
        "sort": [
          35400
        ]
      },
      {
        "_index": "test_so",
        "_id": "06mBPYQBJRm5qR4vd6NE",
        "_score": null,
        "_source": {
          "ProductId": "353924",
          "Name": "Product 353924",
          "ManufacturerId": "54616",
          "UserScore": 25000,
          "CategoryId": "1"
        },
        "fields": {
          "ManufacturerId.keyword": [
            "54616"
          ]
        },
        "sort": [
          25000
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your fast response. The thing is that with the collapse the result is limited by the manufacturer, so not all the product with the same category and manufactured will be shown. Is there any way to recreate the TSQL on my post to elasticsearch?

Comment: Is there any other way to have the results sequentially i.e not have the results grouped into hits?

Comment: Can I see the output you are looking to generate?

Comment: collapse should do what you are asking for enabling the inner_hits option.

Manufacturer 1 
- prod A
- prod B
- prod C

Manufacturer 2
- Prod c
- Prod d

and so on

Comment: Yes, the output I would need is like the second excel table of my post. Thanks in advanced!

Comment: The image of the expected result is https://i.stack.imgur.com/B6eFH.jpg

Comment: But I still see 4 results for the same manufacturer in the second image, the only difference is that in the second image 2 are at the top and 2 at the bottom

Comment: Yes but that´s because there are more results in the query and the "score" are differents

Answer (score 0):

Try following which is assuming all items in Group have same values.  So I used First()

```
var results = products.Where(x => x.CategoryId == 1)
      .OrderByDescending(x => x.UserScore)
      .GroupBy(x => x.ManufacturerId)
      .Select(x => new {ProductId = x.ProductId.First(), Name = x.Name.First(), ManufacturerId = x.Key, UserScore = x.UserScore.First()})
```

Comment: Hi, thanks. I would like to reacreate the TSQL in a elastic search query, not into a lambda expression. I am not sure I can do that in elastic search :(

Comment: What about using rawsql?

Comment: Need it in Elastissearch query or Nest for c#